# Date removal on a LaTeX document

Tags: titles, date

I started to write a paper on LaTeX format, but today's date is displayed after the title. I'm not sure why it is being displayed when none of the commands seem to be indicating it.

Code:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{article}
\title{The Derivative}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
   Learning goals: We start to develop ...
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

How do I remove the date?

Answer (score 3):

`\maketitle` relies on three macros: `\title`, `\author` and `\date`. If you don't specify the latter, by default today's date is used. So you just need to define it as empty:

```
\documentclass[20pt]{article}
\title{The Derivative}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
   Learning goals: We start to develop ...
\end{document}
```